# How to define functions implementing a struct that have the same name, but have different return types

Tags: rust, struct, methods

I want to be able to add two methods to the struct, with the same name, where they would return different data types.

```
struct NumParser<'a> {
    splitting: Split<'a, &'a str>,
}

impl NumParser<'_> {
    fn new<'a>(string: &'a str) -> NumParser<'a> {
        NumParser{
            splitting: string.trim().split(" "),
        }
    }
    fn next(&mut self) -> u32 {
        self.splitting.next().unwrap().parse().unwrap()
    }
    fn next(&mut self) -> u8 {
        self.splitting.next().unwrap().parse().unwrap()
    }
}
```

The returned type would be decided by the annotation or by the type of the variable that I'm assigning it to.

```
let mut parser: NumParser = NumParser::new(String::from("1 2 3 4 5"));

let var1: u32 = parser.next(); // the first next() would be called
let var2: u8 = parser.next(); // the second next() would be called
let arr: [u8; 2] = [parser.next(), parser.next()]; // both times the second next() would be called
var1 = parser.next(); // the first next() would be called, even without annotation
```

I tried using traits, but I can't seem to implement two functions with the same name that way as well.

Comment: I'm not sure it's even possible, but certainly you just better give the two methods different names (`nextU8()` and `nextU32()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite 2 upvoted answers to the contrary, you can define a method with a return type of either `u8` or `u32` (or really any number of and types you'd like) the only caveat is that you can't implement the methods as inherent methods of `NumParser` but that you have to create a trait for them for example like this:

```rust
trait Next<T> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> T;
}
```

Then you can define the 2 methods differing only in their return type as 2 distinct implementations of the trait for your struct:

```rust
impl Next<u32> for NumParser<'_> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> u32 {
        self.splitting.next().unwrap().parse().unwrap()
    }
}
impl Next<u8> for NumParser<'_> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> u8 {
        self.splitting.next().unwrap().parse().unwrap()
    }
}
```

Or if you wish to implement it for every `T` that is parsable (that implements `FromStr`):

```rust
impl<T: std::str::FromStr> Next<T> for NumParser<'_>
where
    T::Err: Debug,
{
    fn next(&mut self) -> T {
        self.splitting.next().unwrap().parse().unwrap()
    }
}
```

and the Rust compiler will choose the method to call depending on the type you need:

```rust
fn main() {
    let s = "12 34 56 78";
    let mut p = NumParser::new(s);
    let a: u8 = p.next();
    let b: u32 = p.next();
    dbg!(a, b);
}
```

Comment: This is what I have been expecting, your solution works best for my question. I have tried creating multiple traits with different names, that produced errors unfortunately. I didn't think about implementing one trait with a generic type. Unfortunately I have to define a function for every type of integer that I want to parse, if that were to be solved as well, I would be completely satisfied, unless it is impossible to figure the type of integer at compile time.

Comment: @Vladislav in this case you can just use BallpointBens answer. Every integer implements `FromStr` so those types are included. Alternatively you can implement my `Next` trait on a generic `T` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Rust has no method overloading, so this is simply impossible. You can either use separate methods (`next_u8`, `next_u32`) or use one method that's generic over things that are `FromStr`. (I've taken the liberty of making `next()` return an `Option<T>`.)

```rust
impl NumParser<'_> {
    fn new<'a>(string: &'a str) -> NumParser<'a> {
        NumParser {
            splitting: string.trim().split(" "),
        }
    }

    fn next<T>(&mut self) -> Option<T>
    where
        T: FromStr,
        <T as FromStr>::Err: Debug,
    {
        self.splitting.next().map(|x| x.parse().unwrap())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut np = NumParser::new("1 2 3");
    println!("{:?}", np.next::<u32>());
    println!("{:?}", np.next::<f32>());
    println!("{:?}", np.next::<char>());
    println!("{:?}", np.next::<u8>());
}
```

```
Some(1)
Some(2.0)
Some('3')
None
```

Comment: Even most languages with function overloading don't allow overloading based on the return type.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer points out, you can't do that in Rust because it doesn't allow method overloading. However, if you don't like multiple functions, there is an alternate solution that doesn't involve multiple function names -- use enums:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Answer {
    Number(u8),
    Text(String)
}

struct Foo {}

impl Foo {
    fn do_something(condition: bool) -> Answer {
        if condition {
            Answer::Number(123)
        } else {
            Answer::Text("Hello".to_string())
        }
    }
}


fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", Foo::do_something(true));
    println!("{:?}", Foo::do_something(false));
}
```

Running it in [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f6ff752b9242c5f4ae57803f8651210f) will show you the following output:

```
Number(123)
Text("Hello")
```